# How are relative paths resolved inside of node packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, path, node-modules, fs

I am making a npm package which, after installation, runs a `postinstall` script located in the `lib/` directory. This postinstall script in turn copies a config file, located in the same directory (as the module), to the user's project's root using `fs.copyFile` function. But I am a little confused about how the two paths are referenced when from inside the `node_modules` directory.

So, long talk made short, I want to figure out what prefixes should I use to refer to files in MY module and for the user's project's directory. Basically, how are relative paths resolved by node when referenced from a script inside the `node_modules` directory?